# Time setting conflict in a dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, time

My dual boot computer has Microsoft Windows and Ubuntu 13.10 installed. Suggestions on this website recommend setting the time parameter for Ubuntu to manual. I did that. In fact, I changed both the Microsoft Windows setting and the Ubuntu setting to manual. However, the time conflict still shows.

Why is Ubuntu picking up the system time setting as GMT + 0.00 and what can I do to change this bizarre error?

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with Windows using local time en Linux UTC. You can fix Linux to use local time or Windows to use UTC:
To fix Windows, just hit Start and type regedit.exe in the search box. Hit Enter and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation. Right click anywhere in the right pane and hit New > DWORD (32-bit) Value. Name it RealTimeIsUniversal, then double click on it and give it a value of 1.

Some how creating a reg file with this option (mentioned in other solutions) doesn't work in W8.1, but this worked for me.